# Websocket dialer maintain the websocket connection

Tags: go, websocket

I am testing with Go websocket dialer to connect with my own websocket server.
This is the dialer code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var (
    ws  *websocket.Conn
)

func main() {

    //add self as sender client
    u := "ws://localhost:5005/ws"
    log.Printf("Connecting to %s", u)
    ws, res, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("[DIAL]", err)
    }
    log.Println(ws)
    log.Println(res)
}
```

and my server code:

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "pubsubserver/pubsub"
    
        "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
        uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
        "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
    )
    
    var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    }
    
    
    func websocketHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
        conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        
        //... some process to add client
    
        fmt.Println("new client connected.")
    
        for {
           //... some process to handle client message
            }
            ps.HandleReceivedMessage(client, messageType, p)
        }
    }
    
    func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            http.ServeFile(w, r, "static")
        })
        http.HandleFunc("/ws", websocketHandler)
    
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":5005", nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("http server err: ",err)
    
            return
        }
}
```

I run my server, the run the `dialer.go`. my server with return some message:

> new client connected.

> 2020/12/03 11:01:19 connection err:  read tcp[::1]:5005->[::1]:55227: read: connection reset by peer

by the log message, am I right to assume the connection is successful, but the dialer close connection immediately after success connected?

How can I get the dialer to persist the connection after connected to the websocket server?

Comment: The connection is dialed successfully. The client program exits after dialing the connection. Is there something you wanted the client to program to do?

Comment: actually i am writing an api handler for the client, which will have various api and automated functions logics to publish data to websocket.

Comment: To keep the connection open, don't exit the application. This seems obvious.  Is there more  to the question?

Comment: sorry for the newbie answer here, but i tought the dialer will keep it open. at the moment it seems like not the case. First time using dialer, so not sure about its behavior. document also did not mention much about that.

Comment: The `Dial` function returns after creating the connection.  The application prints two of the return values from `Dial` and exits the application by returning from `main`.  The `Dial` function cannot prevent the `main` function from returning.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the application form exiting, add the following line of code to the end of the function `main()`:

```
 select {} // block forever.
```

This will keep the connection open, but will not do anything useful with it.